# Copy data from 1 sheet to another sheet with a status as updated

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba macro. I have some data in sheet one column A and B which I want to transfer in sheet2 with status as updated in column c. This macro I created to move the data from sheet1 to sheet2 wherein sheet1 after copying it removes the data from sheet1 then paste in sheet2 with a status as updated in column c below is my code...please helppppppppppppppp.........
[image: Debugs at range]
earlier I coded with for and if statement it was working with for some value and for some it was not, for example, FHH shows were showing as Updated in column c but not FXV for FXV column c status was blank.
now I tried with select again it debugs as a range (i, "B")... all I want is to read the value in column be and show status as updated in the column C... please help also I am not able to define the range i mean it should be for entire column B and C now the limitation is only till 999 can anyone pleas help me on this below is my code...

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

'Copies and cuts the data from sheet1(TIS) and paste the same in sheet2

    Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("A2:A9999").Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2") 'Copy
    Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("A2:A9999").Cut Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2") 'Cut
    Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B2:B9999").Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2") 'Copy
    Worksheets("SampleFile").Range("B2:B9999").Cut Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2") 'Cut
    
'Sheet 2 col C data updated
    
For i = 2 To 9999
   With ws.Cells(i, "B")
     Select Case .Value
      Case "FXV": .Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
      Case "FHH": .Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
      Case "FGA": .Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
      Case "FST": .Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
      Case "FFJ": .Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
      End Select
     End With
     Next i
     
   ' If Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "FGA" Then
'         Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
         
 '        ElseIf Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "FST" Then
         
  '       Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
         
   '      ElseIf Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "FCT" Then
         
    '     Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
         
      '   ElseIf Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "FFH" Then
     
     '    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
         
      '   ElseIf Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "FFJ" Then
         
       '  Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
         
        ' ElseIf Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = "FXV" Then
         
         'Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = "Updated"
       
       'End If
       

End Sub
```

Comment: You have not set `ws` to anything

Answer (score 0):

See comments in code

```vb
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

set ws = Worksheets("sheet2") '<< this needs to be set to a worksheet

'why copy *and* cut ?
With Worksheets("SampleFile")
    .Range("A2:A9999").Copy ws.Range("A2") 'Copy
    .Range("A2:A9999").Cut ws.Range("A2") 'Cut
    .Range("B2:B9999").Copy ws.Range("B2") 'Copy
    .Range("B2:B9999").Cut ws.Range("B2") 'Cut
End With
    
For i = 2 To ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   With ws.Cells(i, "B")
       Select Case .Value
           'you can use a list of values
           Case "FXV","FHH","FGA","FST","FFJ"
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Updated" 'use Offset()
       End Select
   End With
Next i
```

Comment: Please *edit your question* if you want to add something.